# lbgdx - Particle Effect is not rendering

Tags: android, libgdx, rendering, effect, particles

I have a problem attaching a Particle Effect, made by the particle editor, in my android code. It is just not rendered in runtime, even if the duration of the effect should be around 3 sec and it is positioned on the center of the screen. 
As I can see some few other users faced with this kind of problem before but every answer they got didn't help me.
Here is my code:

```java
// in creating 
effect = new ParticleEffect();
    effect.load(Gdx.files.internal("effects/prova2.p"), Gdx.files.internal("effects"));
    effect.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
    effect.start();

//in rendering
    effect.draw(game.batch, delta);
```

Also I tried to change "delta" with my world step value (1/40f) or calling Gdx.graphics.getDelta() but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried scaling it to see if that makes a difference?  `particleEffect.scaleEffect(...)`

Comment: Also check the logs for any loading errors...

Comment: I tried with the scaling and nothing changes, also I double checked for loading errors and there are not.

Comment: you should change the size of the particles in the editor. Experiment with it until you got it right depending on your world width and height

Comment: I'll try but this is strange since I've set the size based on my world units. Indeed my particles are 0.3 and my world is one meter for 160 pixels! Is everything scaled with this costant and everything works except for this particle effect...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're not updating the particle effect.
Try including:

```
effect.update(delta);
effect.draw(game.batch);
```